# Deleting unreferenced objects from a list

Tags: python, list, pygame

**Edit**: Solved. Thanks for the help guys, but it appears that the problem was that the list was overwritten and transformed into a sprite group, rendering all list manipulations useless.

I have recently started programming in python (always sets off the alarm bells), so I apologise if the way I've coded things is slightly scary. This particular program imports **pygame** (the 'engine' being used).

I'm attempting to create a list which contains objects / sprites. This I seem to have achieved, however, I have a problem removing an object from this list once it is no longer needed, as the object does not have a specific pointer as far as I can tell.

The sprite class is constructed as following;

```
class Point(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #Unimportant code

        self.dead=False
        print self
        #This prints; "<Point sprite(in 0 groups)>"

    def update(self):
        if(self.dead):
            #sprList_PointSet.remove(?)
            pass
```

The objects and the list is created;

```
sprList_PointSet=[]
sprList_PointSet+=[Point((50,90))]
sprList_PointSet+=[Point((65,110))]
# ...

print sprList_PointSet
#This prints; [<Point sprite(in 0 groups)>, <Point sprite(in 0 groups)>, ...]
```

Is there a way to remove an instance from the list when it is no longer needed using .remove(x) in a case where there is no apparent memory indicator? If not / or / and could someone recommend a better way of doing such.

Comment: You could use `lst.remove(self)`, but you need a reference to the list inside the class.

Comment: @NiklasB. if `sprList_PointSet` is a global variable, he can reference it just fine, so long as he doesn't try to set it.

Comment: @agf: It would be better design if it wasn't, though.

Comment: Why do you keep such a list anyway? What does it solve, and how are those points removed elsewhere (outside of that list)?

Comment: lst.remove(self) does not work, I tried that first. The list serves several vital roles for collision checking and for sprite updating, it is a global variable.

Comment: You can't remove something if it's not in the list.

Comment: @Niklas B. Would this; "sprList_PointSet+=[Point()]" not be adding it to the list? As I mentioned, I am a beginner to Python, but logically from other programming languages this seems to make sense.

Comment: It doesn't create a new list each time; `lst.append(x)` is identical to `lst+=[x]`. (I tried using `.append()` as well, in case though, to get the same errors). I think this has something to do with the `sprite` class, where something other than a reference is stored in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`self` points to the object you want to remove, so just `remove(self)`:

```
def update(self):
    if self.dead:
        try:
            sprList_PointSet.remove(self)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

`remove` is defined for [mutable sequences](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), and is described [in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Comment: Unfortunately this was what I tried first. It returns the error; "ValueError: list.remove(x): x is not in list"

Comment: @H3katonkheir Then `update` is being called on an object not in the list. You need to handle the error.

Comment: The object is in the list, when I 'print' the list, it shows that there is something there, but does not show any good reference. It shows; "<Point sprite(in 0 groups)>" per object.

Comment: @H3katonkheir I don't have PyGame so I can't test, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @h3katonkheir: I don't think your particular object is in there. Use the `in` operator to be sure: `print self in lst`. I bet this prints False

Comment: It does print False. I do not understand why the lst prints out that it has something in it then?

Comment: @H3katonkheir: "Something" is in the list, but not the object you are looking for. The question is, why is the object's `update` method called?

Comment: @NiklasB.: Hm, I don't understand that. The OP creates a list, prints the list, never deletes an element of that list. Then he tries to delete some object from the list, which fails. How is *when* a problem there?

Comment: @WolframH (I mentioned this is my original post), if I `print self` on a Point object it shows; "<Point sprite(in 0 groups)>", hence, what is self actually referring to? @Niklas B. update behaves perfectly as it should, it is called 30 times per second and the list has been created long before the `dead` variable is `True`.

Comment: @H3katonkheir Have you tried my code with the error supression? Does the item you want removed get removed from the list?

Comment: @H3katonkheir: try putting `def __str__(self): return "dead:%s pos:%s" % (self.dead, self.pos)` in the class definition to get some more informative output. The Sprite class implements `__str__` to give more or less generic information.

Comment: @WolframH `pos` is not defined later than the initialisation of the object, and cannot be called (I really like that %s thing though).

Comment: @WolframH `Please move this discussion to the comments on the question so I don't get pinged on every one.` @H3katonkheir

Comment: @NiklasB I just noticed you edited this answer. Trivial edits are discouraged. I appreciate it when people correct errors (which that _wasn't_, even if it was poor style), but I intentionally left that the way it was so as not to distract from the relevant change.

Comment: @NiklasB. No problem, I just check through my revisions periodically to see what errors people fixed, and noticed this.

Comment: @agf: Sounds interesting. Where can I find this list? :)

Comment: The "responses" tab of your profile -- for you, http://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b?tab=responses&sort=revisions

Comment: @agf: Thanks, just figured that out on myself, too :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [weak references](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) to let an instance disappear when nothing "important" needs it anymore.

Comment: I don't see why this would be necessary in this particular case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case the idea is to get them out of the list, not allow them to be garbage collected -- he'd still have to remove dead references from the list with `weakref`.

Comment: @agf: Sure, but at least the callback will know *which* needs to be removed.